# Android Google Directions API multiple routes

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-directory-api

With google directions API v3 can you can multiple routes for the same location? if yes can someone please explain how can I do it, or any tutorials please? Right now I have only 1 route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes you can get multiple routes to a destination you just need to supply if you want alternatives in your url you send

```
&alternatives=true
```

If you are trying to use this with google maps v2 I created a simple library that can do this

https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator